# Mapping flat fields to sequential records

Tags: mapping, biztalk, edi

I have a source schema that defines a "ShippingCharge" and a "DiscountAmount". My destination schema is an EDI X12 850 message.

[image]

I need to create two "fake" iterations for the SAC loop. I need a way to define that for the first iteration, use the ShippingCharge and the second use the DiscountAmount. There are a few additional "default values" that I need to set to SAC01 that also depends on the iteration (1 or 2).

What functoid should I be using? Any suggestions?

Comment: Off the cuff I'd say this could be solved with 2 `call-template` functoids but maybe there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Table Looping functoid? You can use the table looping functoid to define multiple rows using input links (ShippingCharge and DiscountAmount) and constants (the SAC01 values). The output would then loop through these rows and create the two SACLoop1 elements.

You will need to use the Table Extractor functiod as well to deal with each data value in the table.

Complete instructions on using Table Looping and Table Extractor can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559310%28v=bts.20%29.aspx